# Representar funcion Weibul en Papel logaritmico

Tags: python, matplotlib

Quiero representar el siguiente gráfico y estoy teniendo problemas.

Los datos son:

```
x=[287,349,412,453,492,521,604]
rangoMedio=[0.09459459,0.2297297,0.3648649,0.5,0.6351351,0.7702703,0.9054054]
plot(x,rangoMedio)
```

Si represento esto obtengo una gráfica como esta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría obtener una gráfica de este estilo, con los ejes logaritmicos para obtener una correlacion lineal en la gráfica , para manejar mas facilmente los datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el mismo documento de la grafic ajunta dice:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aún así no consigo dar con la clave
Yo he intentado lo siguiente:

```
x=[287,349,412,453,492,521,604]
rangoMedio=[0.09459459,0.2297297,0.3648649,0.5,0.6351351,0.7702703,0.9054054]
y =[np.log(np.log(1/(1-0.09459459))),np.log(np.log(1/(1-0.2297297))),np.log(np.log(1/(1-0.3648649))),np.log(np.log(1/(1-0.5))),np.log(np.log(1/(1-0.6351351))),np.log(np.log(1/(1-0.7702703))),np.log(np.log(1/(1-0.9054054)))] #Aplico el doble logaritmo al rango medio
plt.plot(no.log(x),y) #represento con escala logartimica normal en el eje x
```

---

Quiero hacer esto pero en python https://la.mathworks.com/help/stats/wblplot.html

---

Muchas gracias

---

**AMPLIACIÓN:**

Estoy tratando de incorporar las etiquetas del 0 al 1 con un paso de 0.1 en el eje y de la siguiente manera y no me funciona:

Mi codigo es:

```
    
    x = np.arange(datos.min(), datos.max(), 0.1)

    rangoMedio = stats.dweibull.cdf(x, parametros[1], parametros[2])
        
    y = -1*np.log(1-np.array(rangoMedio))
        
    predict = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(np.log(x), np.log(y),1))
    
    z = np.exp(predict(np.log(x)))
    
    plt.plot(y, x, 'bo', z, x, 'r')
    plt.xscale("log")   
    plt.yscale("log")
    plt.grid(which="minor")
    #plt.yticks(np.arange(1,10,1))
    #plt.xticks(np.arange(1,10,1))
    etiquetas = (np.arrange(0,1,0.1))
    # etiquetas=np.array(etiquetas)
    plt.yticks(y, etiquetas)
    plt.show()
    print(type(rangoMedio))
```

Como ven he puesto el plt.yticks antes del plot. he probado directamente con la variable etiquetas y luego tambien (comp se ve en el comentario) transformándolo a un array y no funciona en ninguna de las dos maneras

Solucion?

Gracias

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar mejor qué es lo que no te sale?¿No sabes crear la función de Weibull?¿No sabes graficarla?¿Tienes el código que has intentado?

Comment: Ya he actualizado con mi código, el cual no me funciona

Comment: Si requieres obtener los gráficos como en matlab, te recomiendo que veas la biblioteca **SciPy**, en dicho recurso se encuentra el método para graficar probabilidades con [scipy.stats.probplot](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.probplot.html). Puedes definir `x=np.array([287,...])` e `y=np.array([0.09459459,...])` y con ello obtener métricas más rápidas `x.mean()`, `np.log(1/(1-y))`

Comment: Sobre el último apartado: tienes que hacer que el número de _ticks_ coincida con el número de puntos representados. `np.arange(0,1,0.1)` tiene longitud 10, mientras que sólo estás representando 7 valores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma de graficar sólo los datos sería algo así:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [287, 349, 412, 453, 492, 521, 604]
rangoMedio = [0.09459459, 0.2297297, 0.3648649, 0.5, 0.6351351, 0.7702703, 0.9054054]

y = -1*np.log(1-np.array(rangoMedio))

plt.plot(x, y, 'bo')

plt.xscale("log")
plt.yscale("log")
plt.grid(which="minor")
plt.show()
```

[image: gráfica]

Necesitamos crear la *gráfica de Weilbull*, para lo que tenemos que hacer una regresión de los valores logaritmos y crear una función lineal:

```py
predict = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(np.log(x), np.log(y), 1))
```

Para graficarla, tenemos que convertir sus valores con `np.exp()` para poder representarlos en escala logarítmica:

```py
z = np.exp(predict(np.log(x)))
```

Quedando del siguiente modo:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [287, 349, 412, 453, 492, 521, 604]
rangoMedio = [0.09459459, 0.2297297, 0.3648649, 0.5, 0.6351351, 0.7702703, 0.9054054]

y = -1*np.log(1-np.array(rangoMedio))

predict = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(np.log(x), np.log(y),1))
z = np.exp(predict(np.log(x)))

plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', x, z, 'r')

plt.xscale("log")
plt.yscale("log")
plt.grid(which="minor")
plt.show()
```

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Una pregunta.Sería posible mantener en el eje 'y' las etiquetas de los valores de rango Medio? Ya que son valores de probabilidad acumulada, me interesa que, aunque la escala gráfica sea logarítmica, los valores sean los originales (comprendidos entre 0 y 1). Pero al aplicarles y = -1*np.log(1-np.array(rangoMedio)) y luego hacerle escala logaritmica al mismo eje, estamos perdiendo esos valores de probabilidad que me interesan que se mantengan en el eje. Lo ideal sería aplicar directamente la doble escala logaritmica al eje'y' para conseguir esto,y asi no verse modificados los valores del eje y

Comment: Sí que sería posible. En matplotlib puedes poner cualquier valor o categoría para nombrar los _ticks_ en los ejes. Recuerdo haberlo visto en la documentación.

Comment: Sabrías como? Estuve intentandolo con xticks/yticks pero no tuve exito

Comment: Basta con añadir `plt.yticks(y, rangoMedio)` antes del plot.

Comment: Habías editado mi respuesta. He llevado esta edición a tu pregunta inicial. Tienes que hacer que el número de _ticks_ coincida con el número de puntos representados. `np.arange(0,1,0.1)` tiene longitud 10, mientras que sólo estás representando 7 valores.